# Flex wrap layout with boxes that "float left" - make the last row boxes same width as the rest

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, flexbox

I have a layout with boxes. The count of boxes is dynamic depending on what JSON I retrieve from the server. These boxes need to stack in rows and all the contents inside of the boxes must be fully shown, **however the the rows with maximum amount of boxes shoulnd't leave any gaps**.

I've achieved this by using `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent and `flex: 1` on the boxes.

However, if the last row doesn't have as many boxes as the rest of them, they shouldn't strecht all the way to the width of the parent.

[image]

As mentioned - the rows with maximum amount of boxes shouldn't leave any gaps and should take up the whole remaining space

[image]

Is this even possible? And if it is - how can it be done?

Here is a fiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ymcwnbo2/1/

Comment: try with css grid: https://jsfiddle.net/5bqL07ct/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the container

```
justify-content: flex-start
```

and remove flex:1 from the boxes

check this https://jsfiddle.net/ymcwnbo2/

Comment: Yeah, as I've mentioned in my question, this leaves gaps.